# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I created a sample JSF/JDBC project in Eclipse Indigo which is deployed to Tomcat 7. When I put `mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar` in `/WEB-INF/lib`, then I get the following errors:

One from Eclipse:

> Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost (8) was unable to start within 120 seconds. If the    server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.

And another one from Tomcat:

```
SEVERE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of context descriptors to complete
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:574)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:470)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1413)
```

How are they caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: possible hundred duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError%3A+Java+heap+space

Answer (score 3):

As the error says, you are out of heap space. Try to provide more heap by giving following JVM argument when starting tomcat:

```
java -Xmx1024m
```

Actual "right" amount depends about your hardware setup and requirements of application.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat is the process running out of memory, not Eclipse.  Open the Tomcat instance from your Servers view and edit its Launch Configuration.  From the Arguments tab, give it a larger maximum heap size.

Comment: http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/1525/errordh.jpg                    Where should i increase the heap size? Plz help meeeeeee...

Comment: Right there in the VM arguments field.

Answer (score 0):

stop Tomcat v7.0 server and again run it.
You can try to change java heap size

Edit eclipse-home/eclipse.ini to be something like the following and restart Eclipse.
    -vmargs
    -Xms256m
    -Xmx1024m

Comment: I found the eclipse configuration file.How to edit values? How much will i put?Plz explain me???

Comment: you can put minimum 256m and maximum 1024m

Comment: -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
Is it correct ?